# How to profile TemplateHaskell built with Cabal?

Tags: haskell, ghc, heap-profiling, cabal-new

Full project at https://github.com/ysangkok/cabal-profiling-issue

The project contains scaffolding generated by `cabal init`. I'll paste the most interesting source snippets now.

In `Main.hs` I have:

```
newtype Wrapper = Wrapper Int

deriveConvertible ''Wrapper ''Int
```

in `TH.hs` I have:

```
import            Data.Convertible

deriveConvertible :: TH.Name -> TH.Name -> TH.Q [TH.Dec]
deriveConvertible newType otherType = do
  Just newCon <- TH.lookupValueName (TH.nameBase newType)
  v <- TH.newName "v"

  [d|
    instance Convertible $(TH.conT newType) $(TH.conT otherType) where
      safeConvert $(TH.conP newCon [TH.varP v]) = Right $(TH.varE v)

    instance Convertible $(TH.conT otherType) $(TH.conT newType) where
      safeConvert source = Right ($(TH.conE newCon) source)

    |]
```

But if I put `profiling: true` in `cabal.project` and run `cabal build` with GHC 8.6.5 and Cabal 3.4.0.0 (installed using ghcup), I get:

```
    Failed to load interface for 'Data.Convertible.Base'
    Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package 'convertible-1.1.1.0'?
```

What is wrong with the code, and why does it compile without profiling, but fails when enabled?

Comment: If I put the `TH` module into a separate internal library and source folder, and then add the internal library as a dependency of the tests, it works for me.  I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known problem about compile multi-module program that contains TH code for profiling, see related sections in the documentation:

> This causes difficulties if you have a multi-module program containing
> Template Haskell code and you need to compile it for profiling,
> because GHC cannot load the profiled object code and use it when
> executing the splices.

As a workaround, just put `TemplateHaskell` into the `other-modules` in your test.cabal,

```
     other-extensions: TemplateHaskell
```

Then building with profiling (i.e., with the `cabal build --enable-library-profiling`) every thing would be ok.

For more details about why we need `TemplateHaskell` in `other-modules` section, see https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/5961.